# How to center plotly 3d surface plot?

Tags: python, plot, plotly, surface

Trying to plot an intercative 3d surface with plotly (go.Surface), the resulting surface is not centered at origin. It is centered at (10,10) and axes go from 0 to 20. I want it to be centered at origin and axes be limited from -5 to 5. Would be great if someone could help me to do that.

[image]

```
x = np.arange(-5,5,0.01)
y = np.arange(-5,5,0.01)
xx,yy=np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z=xx**2+yy**2

data = [go.Surface(z=Z.tolist(), colorscale='Viridis')]

layout = go.Layout(
...
code here
...
)

fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)

plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename='pandas-3d-surface')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a range for the X and Y axis like this:

```
layout = go.Layout(xaxis=dict(range=[-5, 5]),
                   yaxis=dict(range=[-5, 5]))
```

Note that this requires explicitly specifying the `x` and `y` axis in the data:

```
data = [go.Surface(z=Z.tolist(), x=x, y=y, colorscale='Viridis')]
```

Output:

[image: Plotly surface plot with fixed axis range for X and Y]

See the [official Plotly examples](https://plot.ly/python/3d-axes/#range-of-axes)